# Installing Sharepoint 2013 preview on Windows Server 2012

Tags: installation, 2013

I want to install Sharepoint 2013 on Windows Server 2012, but it says minimum requirement is Windows Server 2008, however I am not able to try it yet, as I am having trouble with installing Network adapter for Server 2012 as you can see in this question,

[Network-adapter-error-in-windows-erver-2012-installed-on-virtual-box](https://serverfault.com/questions/408465/network-adapter-error-in-windows-erver-2012-installed-on-virtual-box)

Anyone know anything about it please let me know as there aint much resources on google I could find regarding this issue.

Now having trouble with NETFX35 while installing SQL Server 2012

```
**EDITED**
```

Problem with my second problem was, while Server 2012 installs .Net framework 3.5 it needs internet to download few files which in my case I could before, on fixing my internet it all worked fine :)

Comment: Problem with my second problem was, while Server 2012 installs .Net framework 3.5 it needs internet to download few files which in my case I could before, on fixing my internet it all worked fine :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Worked for me: server 2k12, SQL 2k12, SharePoint 2k13. This was done on Hyper-V

I did it as a single server installation, joining the server to my existing domain, 
used the full installation option (default) as opposed to the stand alone server.  Beyond that, I accepted the defaults as it's the first time I've played with this edition.

As for Perms, I used a domain account which had local administration permissions on the server, and the ability to manage security within SQL.

Comment: I am stuck with SQL 2012 installation now, its asking me for NETFX35 when i already tried installing using image services and add features, but it just doesn't work :/, any idea cheers

Answer (score 2):

you can check this blog link 
http://bharathtechupdate.blogspot.com/2012/07/installing-sharepoint-server-2013-as.html

i have covered "Installing SharePoint Server 2013 (as Stand Alone) in Windows Server 2012 RC" and also the errors i received and how i did resolved it.

Answer (score 2):

All the steps you needed to install SharePoint 2013 in Virtualbox Environment
http://virtualizesharepoint.com/2012/07/23/install-sharepoint-2013-in-virtual-machine/

Answer (score 1):

what's the exact error message? I believe that's .Net framework 3.5, have you tried installing it via powershell using the ServerManager module?

Answer (score 1):

What i did is install Windows Server 2012 in a VHD image created using Oracle Virtual box and then did BOOT from VHD so that VHD can make full use of my hardware config.

Booted the Windows Server 2012 RC and then installed SharePoint Server 2013 technical preview and all worked.

Comment: I able to install everything now :), but its really slow as i just got 6gb of ram on my laptop :(

Comment: I have 2nd generation iCore7 and 8 gb ram and it is ok performance for me.

What i have seen from some of MVP's is that they use Solid State Drives and it is faster to work. I am also planning to upgrade my laptop to SSD so that i can get some better performance.